Display glitching on Dell XPS 16 with RTX 4060
I just got a new Dell XPS 16 with Nvidia RTX 4060. As usual the first thing to do was wipe the disk and install Ubuntu (tried with 24.04 first, but the same issues below persist with 22.04 too). Unfortunately immediately on boot the display is glitching heavily as shown in the image.

I saw some relevant discussions here and in other forums, but I couldn't figure out anything that could solve my problem. Perhaps I didn't follow some of the more advanced suggestions (that I did not understand), but here is what I have tried so far:

Disabled secure boot
Purging nvidia drivers and installing various versions fresh. No difference between 535, 545, 550 and 555.
Connecting an external display works and that display does not glitch, which allows me to at least work with the device while trying to debug this.
Using the X.org driver solves the issue (maybe, it looked solved the first time but then I switched to nvidia driver which re-introduced it and then back to X.org one and then it didn't seem solved...) Unfortunately the external display doesn't work anymore.
Similarly if I set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" /etc/default/grub, the glitching stops but the external display is no longer recognized.

I am getting desperate and considering returning the laptop, but only have a few days left to do so, so any help would be truly appreciated!

I'm not an expert for this kind of stuff. Did you find errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log ?

Thanks for trying to help anyway! Yes, there are some errors:
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:85:[    52.284] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:87:[    52.284] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:94:[    52.284] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:104:[    52.285] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:106:[    52.285] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.

lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2  and prime-select query please [edit] your question please not as comment.

The solution is here:
Graphics Artifacting with dell XPS 16
"i915.enable_psr2_sel_fetch=0"

Yes this worked thanks for pointing it out!
